# Which collection would be appropriate for this task?

Tags: c#, collections

I am working with C# and now trying to improve an algorithm  (different story there), and to do that I need to have this data structure:

[image: The data structure]

As you can see it is a linked list, where each node can have zero or one "follower"(the right ones). I am still thinking if more than one is necessary.

I could implement these linked lists by myself "raw" but I am thinking it would be much better if I use a collection from the ones available (such as List etc).

So far I am thinking of building a class "PairClass" which will have the a "first element" and a "follower". (the left node and right node). This could change if I decide to include more than one linked nodes(followers). Then using a `List<PairClass>`

One final consideration is that it would be nice if the data collection permits me to get the follower by giving the first element in an efficient manner.

Due to this last consideration, I am not sure if `List<PairClass>` would be the best approach.

Can someone advice me on what to use in these cases? I am always open to learn and discuss better ways of doing things. Basically I am asking for an *efficient solution* to the problem

EDIT: (in response to the comments)

> How do you identify each node, is there an ID? or will the index in a list suffice?

So far, I am content with using just simple integers. But I guess you are right, you just give me an idea and perhaps the solution I need is simpler than I thought!

> What are your use cases? How often will you be adding or removing elements? Are you going to iterate over this collection?

I will be adding elements often. The "follower" would likely be replaced often too. The elements are not going to be removed. I am going to iterate over this collection in the end, the reason being that followers are going to be eliminated as elements of consideration and replaced by their first element

---

(Note aside). The reason I am doing this is because I need to modify an algorithm that is taking too much time, This algorithm performs too many scans on an image (which takes time) so I plan to build this structure to solve the problem, therefore speed is a consideration.

Comment: How do you identify each node, is there an ID? or will the index in a list suffice?

Comment: What are your use cases? How often will you be adding or removing elements? Are you going to iterate over this collection?

Comment: What's the algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to add more details, however by your description

- If you don't need to iterate over the list in order
- If you have a key for each node
- If you want fast lookups

You could use a `Dictionary<Key,Node>`

**Node**

```
public class Node
{
   // examples
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public Node Parent {get;set;}
   public Node Child {get;set;}
   public Node Sibling {get;set;}
}
```

**Option 1**

```
var nodes = new Dictionary<string,Node>();

// add like this
nodes.Add(node.Id,node);

// look up like this    
node = nodes[key];

// access its relatives 
node.Parent
node.Child
Node.Sibling
```

- If you want to iterate over the list often
- If the index is all you need to look up the node
- Or if you want to query the list via Linq

**Option 2**

```
var list = new List<Node>;

// lookup via index
var node = list[index];

// lookup via Linq
var node = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == someId)
```

Comment: I have read your solution carefully, and I like it. There is one thing though: Some nodes have "no follower". I guess I can simulate that by adding a node with the same value as the index, but I don't think that would be too elegant... I appreciate any thoughts on this

Comment: @KansaiRobot Just leave the follower null, i mean in the node class. i think a dictionary might be more where you want to be if you can use a key

Answer (score 2):

In case it is a single follower scenario then I would suggest dictionary of list as a possible candidate as dictionary will make it accessible faster vertically and being a single follower list you can easily use a link list.

In case it is a multiple follower scenario I would suggest dictionary of dictionary collection which will make whole collection faster to access both vertically or horizontally.

Saruman gave a fairly good example of implementation.